# Representations of 2-groups and quantum double constructions

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-field-theory, characters, groupoids, higher-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group. The category of its representations (complex linear, finite dimensional, throughout this whole question) is equivalent to $\mathbb{C}[G]$-modules. V. Drinfeld constructed a quantum double $D(G)$, which is a Hopf algebra, whose category of representations is the categorical center (also called the Drinfeld center) of Rep$(G)$.

The Hopf algebra $D(G)$ can be realized as a crossed module algebra, where the crossed module is given by

$$ 1: G \to G $$

with the conjugation action. By the correspondence between crossed modules and 2-groups [2], one can also realize $D(G)$ as a 2-group, with the set of objects being $G$, and with exactly two morphisms (invertible to each other) between each pair of objects $g$ and $h$. One can show that the Hopf algebra structure of $D(G)$ corresponds to the monoidal structure of the 2-group.

#### Question

So $D(G)$ is really a 2-group. What I'm interested in is the quantum/Drinfeld double of 2-groups.

- (1). Under what kind of representations of 2-groups, does the 2-group have representations correspond to the representations of the Hopf algebra $D(G)$?
- (2). Has one constructed a quantum double of 2-groups, whose category of representations in the sense of (1) give rise to the categorical center of Rep$D(G)$?

---

Possibly related: The character of the 2-representations of a finite group $G$ is a representation of the Drinfeld double $D(G)$. [Theorem on p.7, [1]].

- [1] Representation and character theory of finite 2-groups-[Robert Usher]
- [2] Notes on 2-groupoids, 2-groups and crossed-modules-[Behrang Noohi]-[arXiv:math--0512106]

Comment: The “double” should just be the free loop space, or equivalently the homotopy quotient of $G$ acting on itself by conjugation as in the 1-group case.

Comment: That's a bit concerning.. let G be a 2-group. From Hopf algebra point of view the amount of the objects of D(G) should be the square of that of G.. if I let G act on G naively as groupoids, I don't get as many objects. Also, I'd stress the importance of the monoidal structure on G, which is really why 2-groupoids differ from pure groupoids. Without it, the representation falls back to the case of classical groups (see abstract of [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331931009_On_the_Structure_of_Finite_Groupoids_and_Their_Representations).. and one doesn't see the crossed structures